# Passing image url issue

Tags: javascript, css

Im passing url links like below. There is something weird that i dont understand while passing img stored on my local disc.

Okay so,

```
  sections: [
        {         
          id: 1,
          imageUrl: 'https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png',
        },
        {          
          id: 2,
          imageUrl: 'src/components/directory/dirImages/linkedin-128.pngg',
        },
```

Image under ID 1 is passed correctly:
[image]
Image under ID 2 is passed with the same method as above, however string looks weird in DOM, no slashes at all, and not displaying on my web:
[image]

Im passing it by mapping sections and assigning as prop for my component.

Comment: 1: `pngg` ? - 2: are you sure the web has access to your src/ folder?

Comment: Yes, it is all on local host.

Comment: try with `./src/components/directory/dirImages/linkedin-128.pngg` or `/src/components/directory/dirImages/linkedin-128.pngg`

Comment: double g is typo here, but this is how my url looks like in dom when im passing just relative path copied from vsc:background-image: url("srccomponentsdirectorydirImageslinkedin-128.png");

Comment: Did you try png with just 1 g?

Comment: Yes, this is only example code, in my main i have tried all options you have guys answered, still nothing. I dont understand why this url from disc is turning into this: url("srccomponentsdirectorydirImageslinkedin-128.png")